# How to unset array key if it contains certain string from search array?

Tags: php, arrays

My array print looks like this 
print_r($myArray);

```
Array
(
     [http://link_to_the_file/stylename2.css] => Array
        (
            [mime] => text/css
            [media] => 
            [attribs] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [http://link_to_the_file/stylename1.css] => Array
        (
            [mime] => text/css
            [media] => 
            [attribs] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [http://link_to_the_file/stylename5.css] => Array
        (
            [mime] => text/css
            [media] => 
            [attribs] => Array
                (
                )

        )
)
```

I need to find stylename 2 and  5 and unset them but I would like to find them only by their names and not the full array key. So I placed my search terms in array.

```
$findInArray = array('stylename2.css','stylename5.css');


foreach($myArray as $path => $file ){


    //  if $path contains a string from $findInArray 
       unset $myArray [$path];

}
```

What would be the best approach to this ? I tried array_key_exists but it matches only exact key value. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
foreach($myArray as $path => $file ){
    $filename = basename($path);
    if (in_array($filename, $findInArray)) {
        unset($myArray[$path]);
    }
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/91495)

Comment: @Benn: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$findInArray = array('stylename2.css','stylename5.css');
foreach($myArray as $path => $file ){
      foreach($findInArray as $find){
           if(strpos($path, $find) !== false)
              unset($myArray[$path]);
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was almost there with this , thnx  much!

Comment: I personally think using `basename()` is cleaner (as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21204064/)) Also, I'd use `!== FALSE` instead of `== true`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the PHP `in_array()` function for this.

```
foreach($myArray as $path => $file) {
    if(in_array(basename($path), $findInArray)) {
        unset($myArray[$path]);
    }
}
```